Did the Manhattan Project scientists consider whether the first nuclear test could start a global chain reaction?
It is widely believed that the scientists working on the Manhattan Project at Los Alamos under the supervision of J Robert Oppenheimer from 1942 to 1946, considered, prior to the first nuclear test (the 'Trinity' test, at White Sands proving ground, being a nuclear implosion) that there was a possibility that the resulting inferno could, and might, start a chain reaction that could engulf the whole world.
Some even suggest that the scientists thought it possible that the whole universe could be affected.
The recent film 'Oppenheimer' directed by Christopher Nolan contains dramatic dialogue between Oppenheimer and Einstein which supposes this belief :

Specifically, Oppenheimer reminds Einstein that while the bomb was still being constructed, they had fears that it might accidentally set in motion a chain reaction that would destroy the entire universe. "What of it?" asks Einstein.

Radio Times 03 August 2023
Was this consideration documented?

Why is it skeptical they considered that possibility, when developing the most powerful weapon ever made, with a means that was previously untried? If they never paused to consider that the chain reaction they set off would not stop, that would have been reckless in the extreme. It wasn't that "the inferno would cause a chain reaction" – the nuclear explosion actually is one.

@WeatherVane My skepticism is that scientists would think it possible that a chain reaction begun within a radioactive environment (enriched uranium/plutonium) could then proceed to engulf the entire atmosphere of planet Earth, suffocating all life . . . .  and that they would proceed with such an experiment, it still being 'uncertain', or 'unlikely' rather than "absolutely impossible". But it seems that this was the  case from the answer that I have just accepted. My skepticism is proved wrong. Mission accomplished.

@NigelJ: It's unclear what you're looking for here. There is a non-zero chance that a LHC experiment (IIRC a specific subset of experiments being run) could create a black hole. They're still doing the experiments. So if you disbelieve that scientists could do such a thing: there you have it. But I get the feeling that your question is subtly asserting that the only sane way of engaging with science is if there is exactly zero chance of catastrophe. That is an opinion, not a fact. At best, it leaves the door open to (a) what's close enough to zero and (b) what size of catastrophe.

Relevant XKCD

The chance ofit destroying anything beyond the worldis zero, or less, and this would have been utterly obvious to them. The fact that we and the sun have coexisted for "quite some while" makes it so.

Did they consider the possibility? Yes, and they referred to it as "Atmospheric Ignition" and detailed their calculations in a paper.
Did they think it was likely to happen? No.
The topic is pretty well covered in RealClearScience, where they mention that the issue was initially raised by Edward Teller.
Far from going blind in experimenting right away, they wrote down a paper available here detailing their calculations. Their abstract details:

It is shown that, whatever the temperature to which a sector,
of the atmosphere may be heated, no self-propagating chain of nuclear reactions is likely to be started. The energy losses to radiation always overcompensate
the gains due to the reactions. This is true even with rather extravagant
assumptions concerning the reactivity of the nitrogen nuclei of the air.

Their concerns were tied mainly to the very high amount of Nitrogen present in the atmosphere, which could release enough energy in case of fusion to be self-sustaining, but their calculations led them to conclude:

One may conclude that the arguments of this paper make it unreasonable to expect that the N + N reaction could propagate. An unlimited
propagation is even less likely. However, the complexity of the
argument and the absence of satisfactory experimental foundations
makes further work on the subject highly desirable.

From their conclusion, it shows that there was still some uncertainty regarding what would happen due to the complexity of the topic, and the fact that, well, no nuclear bomb had been detonated before, even if they were fairly confident a global atmospheric ignition was very unlikely.

I just want to point out the difference here between OP's original assertion of impossibility being the only reasonable marker for continuing with the project, versus this answer's focus on it not being impossible, but considered to be sufficiently improbable for them to not pull out of the project.

The article changed "world" to "universe".
There's no doubt they considered destroying the world, see Entropy's answer. The whole universe tho? AFAIK there is no evidence for that in reality nor in the movie. Here is the actual quote from the end of Oppenheimer.

Albert? When I came to you with those calculations? We thought we might start a chain reaction that would destroy the entire world.

"Universe" does not appear anywhere else in the article, the rest of the article discusses the world. Seems like a simple mistake.

The word world sometimes means roughly "universe"; that used to be a major sense, and it's still found in phrases like "the physical world", "the material world", or "this world and the world to come". The film dialogue is apparently using world to mean roughly "the Earth" (or "the surface of the Earth"); I think this answer would be improved by saying that explicitly, rather than repeatedly using the word world as if its meaning were unambiguous.

@ruakh When the answer is contrasting the use of world/universe, it seems pretty obvious that "world" is not being used to mean universe.

@TripeHound: But we're talking about a quotation that uses the word "world" without contrasting it with "universe". It seems pretty obvious that Schwern simply didn't consider the fact that the word "world" is ambiguous.

As if any of us on Earth would know the difference when being nuked... ;-) The scope would encompass everyone here either way. I can see why people on other planets would care about that detail - but I'm afraid it doesn't mean much of a difference from our perspective.

True, the word was changed. But did not Oppenheimer say "worlds" - plural? After Oppenheimer resigned, he later said that it brought to mind words from the Bhagavad Gita - "Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds." Oppenheimer was a Sanskrit scholar, quoting from a text he was familiar with. He spoke these words in the television documentary ‘The Decision to Drop the Bomb’ (1965). He read the original text in Sanskrit, and the translation is his own. I mention this due to “worlds” being plural.  [from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Robert_Oppenheimer ]

@ruakh As a question posed to scientists it is very much a different word.
